# "Error: Can't convert <time> to <character>" when using tidyverse (glimpse) in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, tidyverse, glimpse

I'm a newbie to R and tidyverse. When I try to run glimpse(data), I receive this error:

```
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
Can't convert <time> to <character>.
Backtrace:
  1. pillar::glimpse(data)
  2. pillar:::glimpse.data.frame(data)
  3. pillar:::map_chr(df, format_glimpse_1)
  4. pillar:::map_mold(.x, .f, character(1), ...)
  5. base::vapply(.x, .f, .mold, ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  6. pillar:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 10. pillar:::format_glimpse.default(x, ...)
 12. hms:::format.hms(x, trim = TRUE, justify = "none")
 15. hms:::as.character.hms(x)
 16. vctrs::vec_cast(x, character())
 18. vctrs::vec_default_cast(...)
 19. vctrs::stop_incompatible_cast(...)
 20. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
 21. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 22. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

How do I fix this?

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: somewhere in the data there is data of the class time, which is not automatic converted by the glimpse stack. Find the time class data, and drop or convert it.